# Reset data in stacked chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to reset data in a stacked chart on a button click in highcharts Here is my work so far

http://jsfiddle.net/N9WJ9/1/

It is not working

Can you please help with this one? thanks.

Just to clarify I took the help of below two examples

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Edit on button works for simple graphs, however I could not make it work for stacked columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you are going to have to re-draw the HighChart or initialize the Object again.

```
 $('#button').click(function() {
    $("#container").empty(); 

    options.series = [];
    options.series.push({
        name: 'Test',
        data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    });
    options.series.push({
        name: 'Test2',
        data: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
    });
    options.series.push({
        name: 'Test3',
        data: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
    });
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dane/YUa3R/34/

Comment: @Dane Balia: To destroy a chart, run chart.destroy() instead of just emptying the container. Secondly, you don't have to do this at all as there is the setData() API method.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code in button click:

```
chart.series[0].setData([10, 10, 10, 10, 10]);
   chart.series[1].setData([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]);
   chart.series[2].setData([4, 4, 4, 4, 4]);
```

Check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ruchitrami/YUa3R/1/)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. However, I cant update the name. http://jsfiddle.net/YUa3R/6/ Also can you please help me with how to remove and add series?

Comment: I have discussed renaming the series here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390131/highcharts-show-real-time-value-on-labels/11390353#11390353

Comment: Well your real question of reset of data was answered in this post. But anyways, you are the one to decide the answer.